# I need to output this output formate to web server through flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

My output formate from python code looks like this:

6      3781.0
29     1964.0
116    3075.0
11       99.0
20     3042.0
Name: book_id, dtype: float64

I need to ouput it using flask

Comment: you probably want to take a look at the flask [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#quickstart) guide